# How to edit embed messages - discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How do I edit an embed in `discord.py`?

I have tried

```
msg.edit(embed = embed)
```

but it just edits the message with

```
<discord.embeds.Embed object at 0x000001824D3F5A68>
```

Comment: Please clarify your question, what you are trying to achieve, what is the result at the moment, is there some error messages?

Comment: @vgalin I am trying to send an embed message , then edit the embed message every 1.5 seconds. It edits the message into <discord.embeds.Embed object at 0x000001824D3F5A68>
 instead and keeps editing that <discord.embeds.Embed object at 0x000001824D3F5A68>
message

Answer (score 10):

You should be able to edit an embed of a given message like this :

```
from discord import Embed

...

first_embed = Embed(title='embed 1')
new_embed = Embed(title='embed 2')

# send a first message with an embed
msg = await ctx.send(embed=first_embed)

# edit the embed of the message
await msg.edit(embed=new_embed)
```